# Spring batch - get information about files in a directory

Tags: spring, spring-batch

So I'm toying around with Spring Batch for the first time and trying to understand how to do things other than process a CSV file.

Attempting to read every music file in a directory for example, I have the following code but I'm not sure how to handle the `Delegate` part.

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Bean
    public MusicItemProcessor processor() {
        return new MusicItemProcessor();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job readFiles() {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("readFiles").incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer()).
                flow(step1()).end().build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step1() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1").<String, String>chunk(10)
                .reader(reader())
                .processor(processor()).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemReader<String> reader() {
        Resource[] resources = null;
        ResourcePatternResolver patternResolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver();
        try {
            resources = patternResolver.getResources("file:/music/*.flac");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        MultiResourceItemReader<String> reader = new MultiResourceItemReader<>();
        reader.setResources(resources);
        reader.setDelegate(new FlatFileItemReader<>()); // ??

        return reader;
    }

}
```

At the moment I can see that resources has a list of music files, but looking at the stacktrace I get back, it looks to me like `new FlatFileItemReader<>()` is trying to read the actual content of the files (I'll want to do that at some point, just not right now).

At the moment I just want the information about the file (absolute path, size, filename etc), not what's inside.

Have I gone completely wrong with this? Or do I just need to configure something a little different?

Any examples of code that does more than process CSV lines would also be awesome

Comment: if so, FlatFileItemReader is not for you in this case, you need something like DirectorReader which is to return you a list of files (meta data) only. And then in Processor you will deal with file content ...

Comment: That's a good starting point, I don't know which reader I'm supposed to be using so thanks. I can't actually find any information on `DirectorReader` though?

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31700520/how-to-read-all-files-in-a-folder-with-spring-batch-and-multiresourceitemreader

Comment: That doesn't really help explain how to process a list of files... and goes back to using what you said I shouldn't be using, the `FlatFileItemReader`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After scouring the internet I've managed to pull together something that I think works... Some feedback would be welcome.

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Bean
    public VideoItemProcessor processor() {
        return new VideoItemProcessor();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job readFiles() {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("readFiles")
                .start(step())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step() {
        try {
            return stepBuilderFactory.get("step").<File, Video>chunk(500)
                    .reader(directoryItemReader())
                    .processor(processor())
                    .build();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Bean
    public DirectoryItemReader directoryItemReader() throws IOException {
        return new DirectoryItemReader("file:/media/media/Music/**/*.flac");
    }
}
```

The part that had me stuck with creating a custom reader for files. If anyone else comes across this, this is how I've done it. I'm sure there are better ways but this works for me

```
public class DirectoryItemReader implements ItemReader<File>, InitializingBean {
    private final String directoryPath;

    private final List<File> foundFiles = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());

    public DirectoryItemReader(final String directoryPath) {
        this.directoryPath = directoryPath;
    }

    @Override
    public File read() {
        if (!foundFiles.isEmpty()) {
            return foundFiles.remove(0);
        }

        synchronized (foundFiles) {
            final Iterator files = foundFiles.iterator();

            if (files.hasNext()) {
                return foundFiles.remove(0);
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        for (final Resource file : getFiles()) {
            this.foundFiles.add(file.getFile());
        }
    }

    private Resource[] getFiles() throws IOException {
        ResourcePatternResolver patternResolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver();
        return patternResolver.getResources(directoryPath);
    }
}
```

The only thing you'd need to do is implement your own processor. I've used Videos in this example, so I have a video processor

```
@Slf4j
public class VideoItemProcessor implements ItemProcessor<File, Video> {

    @Override
    public Video process(final File item) throws Exception {
        Video video = Video.builder()
                .filename(item.getAbsoluteFile().getName())
                .absolutePath(item.getAbsolutePath())
                .fileSize(item.getTotalSpace())
                .build();

        log.info("Created {}", video);

        return video;
    }
}
```